# HTTP Header Mime Type in Websphere Application Server 7

Tags: java, spring, http, websphere, mime

I have a Spring Web Application where a user can download PDF and Excel Files. I set the HTTP header for both of them:

```
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"));
    responseHeaders.setContentLength(fileSize);
    responseHeaders.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
    responseHeaders.add("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"" + encodedFileName + '\"');
```

This works fine on Tomcat (the HTTP response is of mime type application/vnd.ms-excel).
But on Websphere 7, the server always return content type: text/html for this request.

*I have already registered the excel content type in the web sphere virtual host, but this does not change anything.*

**What did I missed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, you can't have multiple C-D headers. Like this:

```
responseHeaders.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + encodedFileName + '\"');
```

Also, the code will not work correctly when encodedFilenName contains characters outside the ISO-8859-1 character set.

(dunno whether that's related to your problem, though)

Comment: Julian Reschke: why does the Content-Disposition `"attachment;filename="helloWorld.xls"` not work. (@see RFC2183 http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt)?  -- Thanks for the hint with the encoding. -- But in general it does not explain why it works for Tomcat but not for WAS7

Comment: Well, it should work (new RFC is 6266, btw). You may want to inspect what WAS7 puts on the wire (HTTP trace, browser network console, whatnot...)

Comment: @Julian Reschke: I have done that (WAS7 returns "text/html"): and that is why I asked the question.

Comment: So *did* you try to set it as a single header field?

Comment: @Julian Reschke: may you have overlooked that I use two different methods `set` and `add`. And this is exact the usecase for `add`. Anyway I will test it with only one line.

Comment: "add" is for setting a second header, not for adding to an existing header. You can't use it for headers that do not use the list format (such as Accept)