# Make a link to download local file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, download

In my project (Java SpringMVC3) I get an XLS file via HttpClient and I want that file to be downloaded like it's a real download. A popup window showing download dialog.
How can I do that?

Comment: both answers were useful. I used the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller should copy the content of file to response object. Do not forget - controller function must return NULL. Below I show a working example from my application:

```
String filename = /* path to a file */

File file = new File(filename);

response.setContentType(new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(file));
response.setContentLength((int)file.length());
response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8"));

InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
FileCopyUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());

return null;
```

Comment: why do we need the last two lines ?
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
FileCopyUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to implement a Controller that takes care of the download and specify the response's header-mime type. then you invoke that Controller from the view.

Here is a short example how to specify a header-mime type

[HTTP Header Mime Type in Websphere Application Server 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493192/http-header-mime-type-in-websphere-application-server-7)